# MPMediaQuery using MPMediaPropertyPredicate without punctuation

Tags: ios, nspredicate, mpmediaquery

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *titlePredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:searchText 
                                                                            forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle
                                                                         comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains];
NSSet *predicateSet = [NSSet setWithObject:titlePredicate];
MPMediaQuery *searchQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] initWithFilterPredicates:predicateSet];
NSArray *queryResults = [searchQuery items];
```

Im using the above code to return an array of `MPMediaItems` from the iTunes library where the song title matches `searchText`. However I would like it to match without punctuation, so that for example, songs with "`Don't`" in the title match "`dont`".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way. You'd have to change "dont" in the `searchText` to "don't" yourself. Or, at the expense of some speed, you could fetch all the titles of all the media items and enumerate them yourself; for example, once they were all in an NSArray you could call `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` and at that point your block can perform any test you like.

Comment: I changed from enumerating the array for performance reasons. Although I was hoping this wasn't the case, I've just noticed this is how the search in the Apple music app works, so it shouldn't be a big issue. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I have an app where I gather a lot of info on all songs into arrays as the app starts up, and it really doesn't take very long (I do some of it in a background thread). And after that, enumerating / searching the arrays is extremely fast.